# Необычный слайдер

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Понадобился вот такого рода слайдер http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/
Может кто знает как сделать, или есть уже готовый, нужен именно такой эффект листания картинок.В примере адаптивный сайт и слайдер сделан как я понял через bootstrap, с ним я не очень в ладах,адаптивность не обязательна. Ищу подобный слайдер но через plagin. Буду очень признателен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот слайдер работает без бутстрапа и вполне может быть не адаптивным.

Подобных масса: [1](http://www.skitter-slider.net/), [2](http://wowslider.com/jquery-gallery-dot-seven-demo.html), [3](http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/), [4](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider), [5](http://aviathemes.com/aviaslider/), [6](http://www.egrappler.com/smart-image-gallery-with-twelve-transition-effects-smart-gallery/).

p.s. plugin!

Comment: Кончено спасибо за ссылки, но я все эти сайты просмотрел уже, но я написал, что мне именно нужен такой эффект как на примере, тоесть исчезновение и появление каждого слайда и авто zoom картинки)

Comment: В этих слайдерах он есть.